# MongoDB is not using the index I created for this specific query

Tags: index, mongodb

MongoDB 4.0.

I have a simple query:

```
db.product.find({
        modifiedOn: {
            $gte: ISODate("2019-08-02T03:00:00.000Z")
        }
    })
    .limit(10)
```

And a simple index on `modifiedOn`.

For some reason, the query is taking a long time to run against 40 million docs.

Explain says that the query is using a collection scan (COLLSCAN) instead of an index:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "dbname",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "modifiedOn" : {
                "$gte" : ISODate("2019-08-02T00:00:00.000-03:00")
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "limitAmount" : 10,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "modifiedOn" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2019-08-02T00:00:00.000-03:00")
                    }
                },
                "direction" : "forward"
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "serverhost",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.0.11",
        "gitVersion" : "417d1a712e9f040d54beca8e4943edce218e9a8c"
    },
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1564756397, 18),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1564756397, 18),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"2D2uJyey5qPMYEk17CekUzpdqpU="),
            "keyId" : 6662358951796932610
        }
    }
}
```

This index took some hours to be created. Is there something I don't know with MongoDB that I need to do after creating an index to make it active?

Using `explain("executionStats")` I can see `NO INDEX AVAILABLE FOR THIS QUERY`.

Comment: Once the initial build completes for an index, there isn't an extra step to make a new index active. Can you edit your question to include the output of `db.product.getIndexes()`? Field names are case-sensitive, so perhaps the index wasn't created on the expected field.

Comment: Wow this is really strange...the index I created is not there. I can see it in the " indexes "list, but I can't see it using the comand you told me to use. I will try to create it again and will post the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $hint in your query to enforce your optimizer to use this specific index for the query and post the output.

Thank you!

-Anban